# "Ich bin sicher" vs "Ich bin mir sicher"

Tags: difference, usage

[Dem Wörterbuch](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/sicher) zufolge kann man sowohl

> (a) Ich bin sicher, dass ...

als auch

> (b) Ich bin mir sicher, dass ...

sagen. Gibt es Unterschiede zwischen den beiden Versionen? Ist die eine formeller als die andere? Drückt die eine mehr Sicherheit aus als die andere?

Comment: Hmm, es wäre auch interessant, zu wissen, ob dabei regionale Unterschiede eine Rolle spielen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oberflächlich betrachtet erzeugt das eingeschobene **"mir"** eine verstärkte Betonung, die aber je nach Kontext gewisse Implikationen mit sich bringen kann.

So kann das "mir" andeuten, dass die darauf folgende Aussage für den Sprecher sehr persönlich ist.

Genauso kann das fehlende "mir" bei sehr persönlichen Themen als Distanzierung (oder bei entsprechender Betonung gar als Sarkasmus) aufgefasst werden.

Beispiele (etwas übertrieben, um den Unterschied deutlich zu machen):

> "Ich bin sicher, dass das schon jemand belegt hat" -> Ich vertraue darauf, dass das schon jemand belegt hat. Außerdem je nach Kontext: "Ich hab grad keine Lust/Zeit, das zu belegen" (fauler Student?) oder "Das ist so fundamental, es würde mich sehr überraschen, wenn da noch niemand dran gedacht hat" (skeptischer Forscher?)
>
> "Ich bin mir sicher, dass das schon jemand belegt hat" -> Mein Gedächtnis sagt, dass ich den Beleg schon einmal gesehen habe. / Ich kann mir ein Leben ohne diesen Beleg nicht vorstellen.

> (neutral) "Ich bin sicher, dass Gott existiert." -> Ich habe bisher noch nichts Gegenteiliges gehört und mir dazu noch keine eigene Meinung gebildet.
>
> (gläubig, fromm) "Ich bin mir sicher, dass Gott existiert." -> Ich glaube an Gott und kann nicht ohne ihn leben. Er ist für mich die Grundlage meines Handelns.
>
> (höhnisch, sarkastisch) "Ich bin sicher, dass (dein) Gott existiert." -> Glaub schön weiter an Gott, ich habe da andere Ansichten (und kann mich solange über dich lustig machen).

> "Bist du sicher?" -> Ich habe da so meine Zweifel, was deine Aussage betrifft.
>
> "Bist du dir (wirklich) sicher?" -> Glaubst du (wirklich) an das, was du mir gerade gesagt hast? / Falls du mich bisher belogen haben solltest, ist jetzt deine letzte Chance, mir die Wahrheit zu sagen!

Wie man den Beispielen entnehmen kann, kommt es sehr stark auf den Kontext, den Sprecher und evtl. noch der Betonung an, wie viel Bedeutung man dem "mir" zukommen lassen sollte.

Answer (score 3):

Kurze Antwort: nein. Ich kann beim besten Willen keinen Unterschied erkennen.

Natürlich kann "Ich bin sicher" sich auf *externe* Sicherheit beziehen.

> Puh... ich bin im Bunker. Da bin ich sicher.

Das ist dann "sicher" als *safe* oder *secure*, aber wenn es um "sicher" als *certain* geht, dann sind beide Sätze für mich dasselbe. 
Vielleicht ist die Version ohne "mir" etwas formeller, da sie unpersönlicher ist.